# How to reference child elements in a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to build a parent-child tree in Vue, and I want to pass the parent's DOM/element ID down to the child so that they can append to it. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to achieve as the DOM structure in the browser:

```
<div id="my-id">
    <p>parent-comp header</p>
    <div id="my-id-child">
        <p id="my-id-child-content">child-comp content</p>
    </div>
    <p>parent-comp footer</p>
</div>
```

The only way I have been able to do this so far is to duplicate the `id` into another property `propid` and pass them both down the tree. This seems messy. See my sample code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:v-bind="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<parent-comp id="my-id" propid="my-id"></parent-comp>

<script type="application/javascript">
    Vue.component('parent-comp', {
        props: {
            propid: String
        },
        template: ` <div>
                        <p>parent-comp header</p><child-comp :id="propid + '-child'" :propid="propid + '-child'"></child-comp><p>parent-comp footer</p>
                    </div>`,
    });

    Vue.component('child-comp', {
        props: {
            propid: String
        },
        template: `<div>
                    <p :id="propid + '-content'">child-comp content</p>
                   </div>`,
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#my-id'
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm guessing there must be a better way to achieve this? It seems like it should be a simple task? Thanks.

Comment: Don't muck with the DOM. Model what you want and let Vue render it.

Comment: I can't tell for sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like maybe [slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) are what you need.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with slots but they don't address my problem. Imagine a page with say a hundred identical component instances on them. Each component has a value and some buttons to manipulate it. Those buttons within a component need to be shown, hidden, made active or inactive etc for that particular component only depending on its current edit state, without affecting any buttons in any other component on the page. So I wanted to target each button using its ID.

Comment: I was trying this earlier with Google Polymer and it's easy due to the shadow DOM, so we can repeat DOM ID's all over the page and they are isolated from each other due to the shadow DOM containment. But Vue doesn't use shadow DOM, so now I need to give each button on the whole page a distinct ID so that I can target the one I want to manipulate in my JS without affecting the others.

Or am I looking at this problem wrong? I'm just trying to make fully self-contained components that include all their markup, data and methods for manipulating that component in the same structure.

Comment: I don't want to use vue custom elements here, I tried it and it seems out of sync with the main Vue project in a few places, e.g. the slot directive is different between the two projects.

Comment: You need to stop thinking about manipulating the DOM and instead model what you want. Every item on the page should have a corresponding data structure in your viewmodel and can be manipulated independently using that data structure.

Comment: If you can describe clearly a simple example of the behavior you are trying to get, I'm sure we can tell you how to get it. You're trying to prescribe how to do it, but we don't know what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed better [ways to refer to specific elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) within the current component's template: use [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)s in the template, which would allow your component script to access them via [`this.$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button ref="myBtn">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    doFoo() {
      console.log(this.$refs.myBtn)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The scope isolation is maintained. For example, when there are multiple instances of component `A` on a page, and one of them gets a reference to its button (via `this.$refs.myBtn`) to disable it, only that instance's button is disabled. All other `A` instances are unaffected.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @CatFingers No problem :)